# Easy way to import a post from Word?

Tags: import, microsoft

I have a post written in Microsoft Word with images, text and some formating. Is there some easy way to import this document into WordPress? Either a plugin for Word og perhaps a plugin inside WordPress?

I'm looking for something simple that also converts images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 ways you can import content from Word:

### Paste from Word

There's a button in the editor that allows you to paste content directly from Word.  This removes the special formatting Word uses to lay content out on the page and will make things work well on your site.  (The button is in the "Kitchen Sink" on the Visual editor and is circled in the image below.)
[image]

**Drawback:** you'll have to manually upload and re-add your images.

### HTML Editor

You can also copy-paste your text into the HTML mode of the editor and it will automatically strip out the special formatting Word uses.

**Drawback:** you'll have to manually upload and re-add your images, and you might lose some paragraph spacing in the transfer.

### [Windows Live Writer](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-writer)

The *best* option would be to use the **free** [Live Writer](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-writer) application from Windows.  This is a standalone desktop application that will take in content from Word almost perfectly (including images), allow you to tag, categorize, and set up your post, then remotely publish it on your site.  Live Writer will also upload your images for you and automatically position them in the content just the way you had them laid out in the editor.

**Drawback:** Live Writer only runs on Windows ... so if you're an Apple fan, you're out of luck :-(

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Paste from Word" button in the editor but in my experience, it has been buggy. If you want clean code, your best bet is to just re-create your content within the editor. On the flip side, if you paste from Word, you'll end up editing and fixing its code so much that you'll have wished you just rewrote it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

What about when we have images and formatted content? For advance importing of documents into WordPress Editor, there is a plugin called "Document Importer by Plugmatter" which allows you to import the entire content along with it images, bold & italic words, underlines, etc. It retains all your formatting and does its job in seconds.﻿